# Consuming REST API in Node + cURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, curl, promise

Is there a `Node.js` package to consume `REST API` with `cURL`?

I've tried both:

- https://github.com/danwrong/restler;
- https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client

But for some unknown reason I couldn't authenticate on my VPS provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't find any, so I wrote a wrapper around [node-libcurl](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl) and can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vps-rest-client.

The usage is something like:

```js
var host = 'https://api.budgetvm.com/v2/dns/record';
var key = 'some___key';
var domain_id = 'some___id';

var rest = require('vps-rest-client');
var client = rest.createClient(key, {
  verbose: false
});

var post = {
  domain: domain_id,
  record: 'test.example.net',
  type: 'A',
  content: '111.111.111.111'
};

client.post(host, post).then(function(resp) {
  console.info(resp);

  if (resp.success === true) {
    // some action
  }
  client.close();
}).catch((err) => console.info(err));
```